# What crossover operator should I use for arranging students in classrooms?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I am building a genetic algorithm to solve a "classroom map" problem. The goal is to place correctly students depending on several factors (shortsighted students, turbulent students...).
Here, the genomes is the classroom layout, each classroom has a fixed blackboard and tables positions, what varies is the position of the students.
Now, if I want to cross two classrooms genomes, I can't simply mix both together, otherwise, say that on genome A student "Bob" is on table #3, and that on genome B the same student "Bob" is on table #15, and that the "child genome" gets table #3 from genome A and table #15 from genome B, then, "Bob" would be on two tables at the same time... no really great.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're (probably) doing:

```
0 = Bob
1 = Mary
2 = John
3 = Susan

parents
[2 | 1 | 0 | 3] => John takes first seat, ..., Susan takes fourth seat.
[3 | 2 | 1 | 0] => Susan takes first seat, ..., Bob takes fourth seat.
       ^
one point crossover
[3 | 2 | 0 | 3]   Where is Susan? (and Mary?)
[2 | 1 | 1 | 0]
```

What you can do:

- allow the generation of an invalid chromosome / individual assigning a
  **very low fitness value**. Such individual will be penalized (ignored) during evolution.

  This is very time consuming and not effective
- **repair** an invalid chromosome. It's time consuming but it could work
- use ***ad-hoc* operators**.

  E.g. with **Partially Matched Crossover**:

  [image: PMX Crossover]
  <sup>(from [Genetic Algorithm](http://creationwiki.org/Genetic_algorithm))</sup>

  PMX builds an offspring by choosing a subsequence from one parent preserving as many positions as possible from the other parent.

  > 1. A subsequence is delimited by two cut points. After this, the segments between the cut points are swapped (the positions in yellow). We have the map: 1↔8, 9↔5, 8↔7 and 6↔3.
  > 2. Fill the positions for which there is no conflict. In the example shown, the positions `4` and `2` in both chromosomes (the positions in blue).
  > 3. Use the map to fill the remaining positions (the positions in green). Note that using the mapping 1↔8 in the `o1` vector a conflict occurs again so one must apply the mapping 8↔7 to obtain a number not repeated.

  Other operators are listed in  [Crossover for ordered chromosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)#Crossover_for_ordered_chromosomes) but pay attention to the fact that some operators tend to preserve the relative positions more than the absolute positions.
- **change point of view / representation**.

  E.g. `[2 | 1 | 0 | 3]` or `[3 | 2 | 1 | 0]` are permutations. Standard GA crossover operators produce offspring which aren't permutations. A clever representation of permutations could avoid the problem.

  You can represent a permutation as its [inversion sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509023): for each element `i`, store in `a[i]` how many elements larger than `i` are to the left of `i` in the permutation.

  The only constraint on `a[i]` is that it cannot be larger than `N - i` (`N` is the number of genes).

  Now standard crossover of two valid inversion sequences always produces two valid inversion sequences: no need for special handling of repeating elements.

  This idea is described in [Genetic Algorithm Solution of the TSP
  Avoiding Special Crossover and Mutation](http://user.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~ucoluk/research/publications/tspnew.pdf) (Göktürk Üçoluk).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately I don't understand how the PMX works at all :(

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  Don't do the Crossover;it's not necessary. Just use mutation.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Some believe that crossover doesn't help with genetic algorithms and probably makes performance worse. If you are using crossover, try removing it and see if the performance changes.

Comment: Well, I meant to elaborate the answer not comment, give a proper citation, sources or explicitly state it is based on the experience (or easy to check). Have you seen manlio answer?

Comment: I stand by my "comment". Give it a try.

Comment: "it's not necessary" - how do you know? Where did you read that?

Comment: @Auberon Again, just give it a try. It's easy to do. Let us know if you notice a difference.